Calculating average for each category and for multiple columns
I have a table there rows represent time period. Columns represent different locations "kiosks".
And values represent sales in each kiosk on different times.
Data example:



Date and time
Time categories
Kiosk 1
Kiosk 2
...




2024.01.01 01:00
Monday 01
10
5



2024.01.01 02:00
Monday 02
20
5



----------------
-------





2024.01.08 01:00
Monday 01
15
10



2024.01.08 02:00
Monday 02
20
15




In column B I defined categories for which I would like to calculate sums.
I would like to calculate how sum of sales per kiosk in each of these categories.
Adding aimed result:




Monday 01
Monday 02
...
...




Kiosk 1
25
40




Kiosk 2
15
20





I tried to make pivot table but it requires to add each of column (kiosk manually) and there are too many columns to add by hand.

Please don't paste text/data as images. Make sure you mark your old questions as solved.

If you wanted to use powerquery
highlight data and bring it into powerquery with data ... from table/range ... [x] use as headers
right click and remove first column
right click new first column and unpivot other columns
click select time category column
transform .. pivot column ...  values column: values , advanced aggregate
function:sum
file ... close and load ... back to excel as a table or a pivot table

full sample code from home ... advanced editor ... in powequery
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Source,{"Date and time"}),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Removed Columns", {"Time categories"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Value", type number}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[#"Time categories"]), "Time categories", "Value", List.Sum)
in  #"Pivoted Column"

I notice your title was "average" but your example seemed to be sum. If not change the aggregate function to average in above example
